# Errors When upgrading from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 [MissingFeatures, MissingWebParts, MissingSetupFiles]

Tags: 2013, 2010, upgrade

I have an issue that when I run the precheckupgrade from central administration it shows a lot of errors, these errors are like that:

```
Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [xxxxxxxx].
```

.

```
File [Features\ABC\ABC\ABC.webpart] is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
```

.

```
WebPart class [xxxxxxxx] (class [xxx.ABC] from assembly [XXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=]) is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
```

.

```
Assembly [xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx] is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this assembly.
```

I have deployed the solution (WSP) file ,

after checking i found out that the problem is that the source code I have has different IDs for features and webparts

so are there any workarounds to make this work with the new features IDs

please help me

Comment: is there a chance that you can change the id's back?

Comment: actually i want to change the IDs in the content database to match the IDs in the source code or vise versa, so you think this would be the solution ?

Comment: yes, we also had similar problems and this is the better solution. touching the database is never the better option.